# Get Values From Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Please help me with this guys.
I have this array of objects

```
0: {MealType: Array(4)}
1: {MealType: Array(8)}
2: {MealType: Array(8)}
3: {MealType: Array(4)}
4: {MealType: Array(4)}
5: {MealType: Array(4)}
6: {MealType: Array(4)}
```

How can i Get the values of each array of MealType (with jquery)?
Thanks in advance.

I tried several things with no luck

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't specify the output's format, but for getting all meal types' values you don't need jQuery:

```
const allMealTypes = recipes.flatMap(recipe => recipe.MealType);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap